# doctrine2 ldap DBAL driver

Tags: ldap, driver, doctrine-orm

Are there any plans for an LDAP DBAL driver for doctrine2?

[driver docs](http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/dbal/2.0/docs/reference/configuration/en#getting-a-connection:driver)

Comment: I just stumbled upon https://github.com/chanmix51/SlapOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doctrine DBAL is for SQL, is there a way to translate SQL into LDAP Queries? If then yes we could support it for DML statements. Its not planned and will have to be a community effort if implemented.

Comment: Had a quick search but could see anything, i'll put it on the back burner for now.